# Mapbox: Marker, and point layer position is not equal on higher zoom level

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

In my map project, I had a layer of type "cirlce"

```
map.addLayer({
            id: id,
            type: "circle",
            source: source,
            filter: ["!", ["has", "point_count"]],
            paint: {
                "circle-color": "red",
                "circle-radius": 4,
                "circle-stroke-width": 1,
                "circle-stroke-color": "#fff",
            },
        });
```

In the map render event, I created a marker for each point:

```
                    marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
                    anchor: 'center'
                }).setLngLat(coords).setPopup(popup);
```

At a low zoom level, marker and point displayed in the same position. But if I zoom in, the marker drifts away from the target. Both, point layer and marker uses the same source/coordinates. It looks like the position values of the marker are calculated wrong. What can I do?

low zoom level:

[image]

high zoom level:

[image]

Comment: Your `anchor` should be `"bottom"`. I'm not sure that explains the whole gap though.

Comment: Setting `anchor` to `"bottom"` sadly makes no difference. The calculation of the CSS translate is wrong...

Comment: There is something very weird in your project. But we can't tell what that is without a codepen or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The only solution I found is to remove the markers at high zoom levels and re-create them after each zoom event. Then the position is calculated correctly.

```
        map.on('zoom', () => {

           const zoom = map.getZoom();

           //recalculate markers cause position is inaccurate
           if (zoom > 15) {

               //remove Markers
               if (markersOnScreen!==null) {
                   for (let key in markersOnScreen) {
                       if (markersOnScreen.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                           markersOnScreen[key].remove();
                       }
                   }
               }

               //create new markers
               markers = {};
               markersOnScreen = {};
               updateMarkers();
           }
        

        });
```